# Where can i download Video(Graphics) and Audio driver for my Laptop with NVDIA Graphics Processor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hp

I need the Video driver or the Graphics Driver for my Hp pavilion laptop with NVIDIA processor. And i need the Audio driver for the same laptop configuration. Where can i find those drivers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional drivers can be installed via the *Driver* application as briefly described here:

[How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

In the latest Ubuntu version:

1. Open *System Settings*
2. Click on *Additional drivers* tab

*If there are additional drivers available for your system, you'll see them here.*

3. Install the driver(s)